# How to setup ACL in Windows share

Tags: windows, acl

I need to setup ACL in a windows share folder where:

- There is one main folder
- Inside this folder there are many subfolders, every users should write/read inside these subfolders what they want
- Nobody but the administrator should delete or add new files and folders in the main folder

The question is: is there an ACL setup for this requirements for the mainfolder to avoid to set particular ACL for every new added subfolder?

Comment: I've completed this before by setting an explicit DENY with DELETE on the top level folder and ensuring it only applied to "This folder only" but look at this from an elevated command line and test first.... **`FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /b /a:d "\\server\share\topfolder\*"') DO icacls "\\server\share\topfolder\%G" /deny "<everyusergroup>":(DE)`** and/or also **`icacls "\\server\share\topfolder" /deny "<everyusergroup>":(DE)`**... you may or may not find this helpful... see [ICACLS](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html)... but you can do this through Folder properties as well manually.